Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager. How can i solve?
I created a simple android app in react native and until recently, my app launched with:
npx expo start
Subsequently I used the QR code to use it on Android smartphones. Now I would like to publish the app and I was advised to create the android folder using the command:
npx expo run:android
The problem is that when the app is started I get this error immediately after the splash screen:
ERROR  Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager.

This error is located at:

in RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig (created by HeaderConfig)
in HeaderConfig (created by SceneView)
in RNSScreen
in Unknown (created by InnerScreen)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in NativeStackNavigator (created by App)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes

And this is my package.json:
{
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.18",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.21",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.41.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "expo": "^49.0.23",
    "expo-av": "~13.4.1",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.3.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "native": "^0.3.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.10",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.9.0",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.1",
    "react-native-webview": "13.2.2",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}

How can i solve this error? My app doesn't running now
